# Org export dispatcher missing options

Tags: org-export

I'm running Emacs (Emacs version: 25.2.2; org-mode version: 9.2.6-4-ge30905-elpa) on Linux Mint Ubuntu.

If I try to export my org file or subtree (`C-c C-e`) I get the dispatcher buffer without any option despite the fact that they are activated in the settings.

[image]

[image]

I don't have latex, odt, ... export options showing up in the dispatcher. How can this be possible? How can I fix this weird behavior?
I updated all the installed packages.

Comment: Does the value of the variable `org-export-registered-backends` include the backends you expect (latex, odt, ascii, html, icalendar)? Look for entries like this: `#s(org-export-backend :name html ...`. The entries in the menu are calculated from this variable, hence the question.

Comment: I can not find this variable in the options or inside my init file either... If I try `customize variable` I can select only the `org-export-backends` option

Comment: You can use `C-h v` to see the value of any variable: try `C-h v org-export-registered-backends RET`.

Comment: I get `no match`...

Comment: What version of Org mode  and emacs are you using? Please update the question with that information, which you can get with `M-x org-version` and `M-x emacs-version`.

Comment: Ok, now it is specified in the first line